# Make words in comments selectable in the iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

In the iOS app, I can't select a word in a comment to look up its definition. Can you make this possible?

Comment: Test comment...

Comment: No iOS so not sure, is this the same as this one? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279229/trying-to-select-text-in-comments-will-select-the-whole-word-even-when-i-dont

Comment: @ShadowWizard no, that's armor selecting text during writing comment. Mine is about selecting text in a comment posted.

Comment: Can't you just click 'copy' then paste it somewhere and extract what you need?

Comment: @Insane of course I can do that, it's just not intuitive to do that